# Что мне нужно для работы Blazor приложения на клиенте и на сервере?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

Я запутался.
Создал Blazor WebAssembly приложение. Простое с кнопкой и с вычислением числа. Также в приложение добавил телеграмм бота в `Main` строкой `Bot.StartAsync();` которая запускает телеграмм бота который просто отвечает на сообщение.
**Я думал что оно будет работать так:** Приложение крутится на сервере, человек в боте пишет `/start` ему бот выдаёт ссылку на приложение. Переходим по этой ссылке, попадаем в приложение которое работает в браузере и делает вычисления в браузере. В приложении меняются DOM элементы, удаляются и появляются визуальные блоки и данные. Все это высчитывается на клиенте. Далее человек жмёт отправить данные и данные отправляются запросом в контроллер на сервере. 
**Как оно работает:** Всё приложение и телеграмм бот были скомпилированы в WASM приложение, и только если я зайду в это приложение только тогда запустится телеграмм бот.

На сколько я понял Blazor Server будет обрабатывать на сервере даже команды `count++;`.
А мне нужно вот так: Юзер заходит на сайт. Сайт обращается к серверу для получения данных. Далее юзер жмёт кнопки, данные обрабатываются на клиенте. Потом юзер жмёт кнопку отправить. Данные отсылаются на сервер.
Вот вопрос что мне нужно для реализации моего приложения?
Blazor Hybrid подойдет? Нет возможности его потыкать, нужно 10гб а них нет свободных(
Или же мне нужно Blazor WebAssembly и WebAPI? Где Blazor WebAssembly приложение будет делать запросы к WebAPI? И телеграмм бот будет висеть в приложении вместе в WebAPI.

Comment: Создайте простой ASP.NET проект, для ваших задач будет достаточно.

Comment: Мне нужна скорость и интерактивность в приложении. А JS я не знаю.

Comment: И...? Это не отменяет того факта, что все перечисленное вы сделаете на простом ASP проекте, и даже проще будет. Blazor хорош тогда, когда вам нужен сайт, который умеет синхронизироваться между пользователями, например, чат, где вы в реальном времени должны видеть все сообщения, то есть у вас должна быть тесная связь со всеми. Осуществляется это при помощь открытия соккет соединений (и не только) через SignalR. Ну а вы говорите сейчас про телеграмм бота, который должен вам открыть сайт где человек что-то делает и по нажатию кнопки отправляет на API запрос... Похоже это на "реал тайм"?

Comment: Не, вы конечно должны лучше меня знать что вам надо, но пока, по вашему описанию, вы пытаетесь использовать совершенно неподходящую технологию для своего проекта. Повторю, простой ASP.NET решает все описанные вами задачи с легкостью и без лишнего геморроя, особенно что касается API и телеграмм бота, а вот открытие ссылки - зависит от того что там должно быть, ну в любом случае, сгенерировать ссылку для человека и по ней попросить перейти труда не составит, ну а там уже нужный вид, нужная форма/объекты и кнопка "отправить". Стандартная логика большинства сайтов.

Comment: Как в ASP.NET MVC я могу без JS интерактивно менять данные на странице? Как я по клику могу перестроить страницу без обращения к серверу и не перезагружая страницу?

Comment: Встречный вопрос, а как вы сделаете без JS на Blazor?) Вы от этого не убежите, ибо WEB это HTML и JS, ничего более. Да, можете часть JS заменить на C# код, но этот C# также будет преобразован в JS и такая возможность есть как в Blazor так и в обычном ASP. Повторю, разница в том, что Blazor - это **реал тайм**, то есть между сервером и клиентом открывается прямое соккет соединение, по которому идет общение, на основе которых что-то делается и на сервере и на клиенте. Тоже самое соккет соединение (если нужен реал тайм) вы также можете реализовать в пару строк кода на ASP. Подумайте над этим...

Comment: Ну вот сейчас у меня то приложение которое я сделал без сервера меняет HTML код, js я не использовал. Смысл не в том что без js а в том что я не знаю js что бы на нём писать.

Comment: Вы меня не хотите походу понимать. Чтож, удачи в реализации вашей задумки.